# Are there words for these?

Tags: single-word-requests

If my fingers and toes are all cold, I can say "My digits are cold." However, if my shoulders and hips are aching, (or elbows and knees, or wrists and ankles), I don't know of a word to collectively describe these  "similar" parts of the body. 
Anybody know of any words to describe these?

Comment: 'Joints' is the hyper-hypernym.

Comment: If *joints* covers too many joints, and *limbs* covers too many parts of the limbs, then why not use *limb joints*?

Comment: Nice suggestion but not one word!

Comment: @user292631 Then you haven't specified your concept clearly enough. You seem to want one word for 'shoulders, hips, elbows, knees, wrists, ankles, fingers and toes'.  fingers and toes are not joints, but maybe you really mean your finger and toe joints.  Are you being informal or are you a doctor listing symptoms?

Answer (score 2):

Joints is the best option. You can call you fingers and toes your carpels and tarsals respectively, if you're referring to the lower-digits.

Comment: Thanks, but joints is non-specific. Also, fingers and toes are phalanges. Carpals and tarsals are bones in the wrists and ankles respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing an extremity (extremities - plural) of the body.

The definition, from dictionary.com is given as:

2. a limb of the body.

I feel like that works well.

Comment: Thanks, but limbs refers to the whole legs/arms, not specific areas of them.

Answer (score 0):

Hips and shoulder joints can be called *[ball-and-socket joints](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ball-and-socket%20joint)* or *spheroidal joints*, but telling someone other than a medical professional that your ball-and-socket joints are sore is pretty likely to gain you an odd look-- these terms are not widely used in casual conversation.